# Crystal Report not displaying in Crystal Report Viewer WPF

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

I cant seem to find out what is happening on the clients pc.

The development was in Visual Studio 2013, using SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer (image attached for version details). I get no exceptions too.

Client PC (OS - Window 7 (64bit) ) Tried installing both CR_13 Runtime (64 & 32 bit) 
[image: Client Installation]

Development PC (OS - Windows 10 Pro (64bit))
[image: Development PC]

[image: Crystal Report Version Details]

Comment: Maybe you should set the assembly to be copied to the output directory?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I tried your suggestion nothing changed . :(

Answer (score 0):

So I went on reading issues people experienced with Crystal Report not loading or showing the report. I decided to take my code apart and went old school.

This line was the bug - `report.Load("../../Report/rptCustomerQuestionnairePhysical.rpt");`

I noticed on the client machine report.Load() could not locate the file.

Because I also registered to the Loaded Routed event - `this.crystalReportsViewer1.Loaded += crystalReportsViewer1_Loaded;`

I got a strange behavior of the viewer showing but the report not loading. Which I suspect an exception might have been stuck in the stack trace (hidden).